# EVGA gtx960 Super AC 2.0 - Wrong colour pallette while using CRT monitor and DVI-i to VGA Adapter

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, dvi, crt

I'm experiencing a weird issue where my monitor, an old 19" CRT basically show close to no green levels. The monitor works flawlessly on another computer and I have tried 2 DVI-I to VGA connectors (one that came with the evga card and another one from an AMD card) to no avail.

Windows 7 SP1 - Asus Maximus Hero VII - 32GB DDR3 1600

Comment: Are you using VGA or real DVI (not DVI-A with VGA's analog signals in a DVI form factor). Asking because VGA has three lines for colour. Once of which is green....